# Composition of two functions - Taylor series

Tags: proof-writing, taylor-expansion

Let $f$ and $g$ be $n$-times differentiable functions, and let us assume that the composition $ F (x) = f (g (x)) $ is well-defined on an interval.

Let us say that the composition is also $n$ times differentiable.
Then we assume that $f$ and $ g $ are defined near 0 and that $ g (0) = 0 $ such that the composition $ F (x) = f (g (x) ) $ is also defined close to 0.

Now let $ P_n $ and $ Q_ {n} $ be the Taylor polynomials of order $ n $ of the functions $ f $ and $ g $ at the position 0.
I want to prove that the Taylor polynomial $ T_{n, F} $ of order $ n $ of function $ F $ consists of all monomials $ c_{k} x ^ {k} $ of degree $ k \leq n $ of that Polynomial $ P_ {n}(Q_ {n} (x))$.

Now I have done some calculations on my own and I tried this:

$$T_{n, F}(x)=\sum_{k=0}^{n} \frac{(f \circ g)^{(k)}(0)\cdot x^{k}}{k !}=\sum_{k=0}^{n} \frac{(f(g(0)))^{(k)}\cdot x^{k}}{k !}$$
$$P_{n}\left(Q_{n}(x)\right)=\sum_{k=0}^{n} \frac{f^{(k)}(0)}{k !}\left(\sum_{k=0}^{n} \frac{g^{(k)}(0)}{k !} x^{k}\right)^{k}$$

I wanted to show that $$T_{n, F}(x)-P_{n}(Q_{n}(x))=0.$$ But I have not reached any Important result and maybe my approach is wrong and I understood something wrong.

I read something in the internet about Faà di Bruno's formula generalizing the chain rule to higher derivatives and additionally I read somethig about the multinomial theorem and I found similar terms in both equations but yeah, that's all I have.

Any kind of help would be very helpful, thanks in advance!

Comment: The composition $ P_n(Q_n(x)) $ will give the right result if $ Q_n(0)=0$.

Comment: @hamam_Abdallah Well it says that $g(0)=0$ so the Taylorpolynomial needs to have the same characteristic, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With Taylor-Young formula,
for $ X $ and $ x $, near zero,

$$f(X)=P_n(X)+X^n\epsilon(X)$$
$$g(x)=Q_n(x)+x^n\epsilon(x)$$

where $ Q_n(0)=0 $. so

$$f(g(x))=P_n(Q_n(x)+x^n\epsilon(x))+(x(R_{n-1}(x)+x^{n-1}\epsilon(x)))^n\epsilon(x)$$
$$=P_n(Q_n(x))+x^n\epsilon(x)$$
the terms of degree $\ge n $ are included in the remainder.

Comment: Thank you, can you maybe rewrite it using the little-o notation for the remainder? I am not used to the Taylor-Young formula...

Comment: @calculatormathematical $$x^n\epsilon(x)=o(x^n)$$ For example $ X^4\epsilon(X)=o(X^4)$.

Comment: And $$(x(R_{n-1}(x)+x^{n-1}\epsilon(x)))^n\epsilon(x)=o(x(R_{n-1}(x)+o(x^{n-1}))^n)$$ ?

Comment: @calculatormathematical $$=x^n(R_{n-1}(x)+x^{n-1}\epsilon_1(x))^n\epsilon_2(x)=x^n\epsilon_3(x)$